# Mysql Query Log (result of queries)

Tags: mysql, logging

Is there exist Mysql log which write sql queries and their results?

**Note:** Results i mean success, warning or error (in case warning and error writes warning or error texts)

I know general_log  but it is only writes queries not  their results also .

Comment: Success can only mean ran without error. SQL cannot discern whether a query did the 'right' thing.

Comment: Ok @P.Salmon maybe but what about warning and error?

Answer (score 0):

To find queries with errors or warning,
see `TABLE performance_schema.events_statements_summary_global_by_event_name`.

Columns `SUM_ERRORS` and `SUM_WARNINGS` will show how many time the specific query failed.

Also of interest, there are statistics on errors in the server,
see `TABLE performance_schema.events_errors_summary_global_by_error`.

Reference manual:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/statement-summary-tables.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-summary-tables.html

Comment: I do not want know sums. I want know reason of warning or error for specified query.